# Design consideration for tablet pc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tablet

I am developing a web applicaiton which will generally be accessed through browser.

My client says that he will also access the web application from a tablet pc. So do I need to consider  something especially from GUI point of view for tablet pc?

Answer (score 2):

2 major things to consider:

- Smaller screen size
- Lack of the ability to hover

Answer (score 1):

If the web app targets both PC users and tablets you should consider using CSS3 media queries to serve different css files based on the browser resolution. 
[LessFramework](http://LessFramework.com) can help a lot with this.

I saw a nice but brief intro to media queries [here](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/05/responsive-design-using-css3-media-queries/)